# Is there a way to get a buy on amazon button on my own app? (an api or so)

Tags: amazon-product-api

i am currently working on an app where i want to merge multiple E-commerce websites and be able to have certain products from them listed basically allowing to search over prices and products from multiple sites. is there any API that i could use to do so for amazons product listings?

Answer (score 0):

> ### Audience
>
> This guide is intended for developers who want to build an e-commerce
> storefront that sells items listed on Amazon.com, or an application
> that helps others build e-commerce storefronts.

source: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/